# Shiny App Date widget- start with blank field

Tags: r, date, shiny

I have a Shiny app date picker widget (dateInput), and I want the starting date to be blank- no date at all. Essentially I want the form to save nothing, or NA unless a user selects a date with the widget. I sort of got this to work by putting `value = ""` in the code, but I am having problems with a blank date writing to data on the server side, and I get warnings because "" is not in yyyy-mm-dd format. Can you help?

I did see this post: [Setting date range picker start date to blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251020/setting-date-range-picker-start-date-to-blank) but this is a different widget than I am using.

```
...
dateInput("coap_injail_infodissemination_date", label = "Information Dissemination - Date Referred:", value = "", format = "mm/dd/yyyy",
            startview = "decade")
...
```

[image]

Comment: Could you use `value = as.Date(NA)` here?

Comment: I'll check it out! Thank you. On second review we may be moving to just a text entry field, instead of using this date widget. This way the field will be blank and we will provide instructions to enter in MM/DD/YYYY format