# How to set the default value of Date Range Picker to null

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I am using Laravel framework. I want to create a date range filter using ajax. but I have a problem with the daterangepicker that I [use](https://adminlte.io/themes/dev/AdminLTE/plugins/daterangepicker/)

this is my [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ButIM.png)

this is the field code

```
<input type="text" class="form-control filter" id="filter-date">
```

this is the javascript code to call daterangepicker

```
    $(function () {
    //Date range picker

    $('#filter-date').daterangepicker({
      autoUpdateInput: true,
      locale: {
          cancelLabel: 'Clear'
      }
    });

    $('#filter-date').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('YYYY/MM/DD') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('YYYY/MM/DD'));
    });

    $('#filter-date').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        $(this).val('');
    });
  })
```

This is the javascript code to hold the value of daterangepicker, before sending it to the controller using ajax. (accommodated in variable datefilter)

```
    let datefilter = $("#filter-date").val()
    $(".filter").on('change',function(){
      datefilter = $("#filter-date").val()
      console.log(datefilter)
      table.ajax.reload(null,false)
    })
```

When I use the code above and *console.log(datafilter)*, the value in datefilter goes straight in, which is today. but I want the first or default value to be null.
I managed to change the default value to null with **autoUpdateInput: false**. but after I fill in the date I want to sent, the value of datefilter is always null.
Is there any other way for the default value to be null, but using the **autoUpdateInput: false** method?

Answer (score 0):

Please try setting `autoUpdateInput` to `false`.

> [Originally Answered by Sumanth Hegde](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70417790/4056660)